# Elasticsearch max file descriptors too low

Tags: magento2.3, elasticsearch

When I tried to launch Elasticsearch - I get an error

```
[2019-05-28T23:08:59,142][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [protectcovers-1] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9300}, {[::1]:9300}
[2019-05-28T23:08:59,236][WARN ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [protectcovers-1] max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65536]
[2019-05-28T23:08:59,237][WARN ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [protectcovers-1] max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
```

curl -i localhost:9200/

```
{
  "name" : "protectcovers-1",
  "cluster_name" : "protectcovers",
  "cluster_uuid" : "_na_",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.6.1",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "1fd8f69",
    "build_date" : "2019-02-13T17:10:04.160291Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.6.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

/etc/security/limits.conf file

```
#*               soft    core            0
#root            hard    core            100000
#*               hard    rss             10000
#@student        hard    nproc           20
#@faculty        soft    nproc           20
#@faculty        hard    nproc           50
#ftp             hard    nproc           0
#ftp             -       chroot          /ftp
#@student        -       maxlogins       4
elasticsearch   soft    nofile          65536
elasticsearch   hard    nofile          65536
elasticsearch   memlock unlimited
```

Answer (score 1):

See the [Elastic docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/vm-max-map-count.html) on virtual memory.

On linux you can run `sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144` to fix your problem